# Sort a list of dictionaries...(Itemgetter)

Tags: python

I want to group a list of dictionaries by a key. The following code is working.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
user_dict = {123: [
                {'the_id': 1, 'title': 'Title1'},
                {'the_id': 1, 'title': 'Title1'},
                {'the_id': 3, 'title': 'Title3'},
                {'the_id': 2, 'title': 'Title2'}
]}

for user in user_dict:
    for id, value in groupby(user_dict[user], key=itemgetter('the_id')):
        titles = []
        for k in value:
            titles.append(k['title'])
        print(titles)
```

It results:

```
['Title1', 'Title1']
['Title3']
['Title2']
```

When I change the order in the dict, the "grouping" doesn't work anymore.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
user_dict = {123: [
                {'the_id': 1, 'title': 'Title1'},
                {'the_id': 3, 'title': 'Title3'},
                {'the_id': 2, 'title': 'Title2'},
                {'the_id': 1, 'title': 'Title1'}
]}

for user in user_dict:
    for id, value in groupby(user_dict[user], key=itemgetter('the_id')):
        titles = []
        for k in value:
            titles.append(k['title'])
        print(titles)
```

This results to:

```
['Title1']
['Title3']
['Title2']
['Title1']
```

Can someone explain me that? How is the code correct?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the list of dictionaries before passing it to the groupby function to ensure grouping based on the `'the_id'` key.

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

user_dict = {123: [
                {'the_id': 1, 'title': 'Title1'},
                {'the_id': 3, 'title': 'Title3'},
                {'the_id': 2, 'title': 'Title2'},
                {'the_id': 1, 'title': 'Title1'}
]}

for user in user_dict:
    sorted_list = sorted(user_dict[user], key=itemgetter('the_id'))
    for id, value in groupby(sorted_list, key=itemgetter('the_id')):
        titles = []
        for k in value:
            titles.append(k['title'])
        print(titles)
```

Comment: Thx a lot. I'll take your solution

Comment: Note that the use of the `sorted` function increases the time complexity from *O(n)* to *O(n log n)*, which may be significant when the input list gets large.

Comment: You're right. 
@ saromba You should take the answer @blhsing give below as it is the better one

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.groupby` groups consecutive items of the same key, not items that are of the same key but separated by other items.

You can use a dict of lists instead to store titles of the same id in the same sub-lists:

```
titles = {}
for users in user_dict.values():
    for id, title in map(itemgetter('the_id', 'title'), users):
        titles.setdefault(id, []).append(title)
print(*titles.values(), sep='\n')
```

This outputs:

```
['Title1', 'Title1']
['Title3']
['Title2']
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/hOsh4m

Comment: I take the solution from the upper post. Thanks anymore.

Comment: The answer is the better one

Answer (score 0):

Both are the expected output.

> The operation of groupby() is similar to the uniq filter in Unix. It generates a break or new group every time the value of the key function changes (which is why it is usually necessary to have sorted the data using the same key function). That behavior differs from SQL’s GROUP BY which aggregates common elements regardless of their input order.

Source: [Python3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)